# What's the difference between these two enum declarations in swift?

Tags: swift

```
enum MyEnum {
    case A, B, C
}

enum MyEnum2 {
    case A
    case B
    case C
}
```

What's the difference between these two enum declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between the two syntaxes - it is your personal preference to use one vs. the other.

Swift allows you to add separate `case`s to a single `enum` so that you could group `enum` constants with similar associated values, e.g. like the book example of `Barcode`:

```
enum Barcode {
    case UPCA(Int, Int, Int, Int)
    case QRCode(String)
}
```

For situations when you define "plain" `enum`s with no associated values, either one of these two syntaxes would be a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's also probably worth mentioning that unless you define a type and initialize the first element, the enums won't have any raw values.

```
enum MyEnum {
    case A, B, C
}

let myEnum = MyEnum.A
let myEnumRawValue = myEnum.rawValue
```

will fail with an error 'MyEnum' does not have a member named 'rawValue'.

```
enum MyEnum:Int {
    case A = 0, B, C
}

let myEnum = MyEnum.A
let myEnumRawValue = myEnum.rawValue
```

will not fail.

If you don't want to declare a type or initialize the enums, but still get a number (maybe indexed from some base) you could also write:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case A, B, C

    func enumIndex(base:Int) -> Int {
        switch self {
        case .A:
            return base
        case .B:
            return base+1
        case .C:
            return base+2
        default:
            return base
        }
    }
}
```

In this case

```
let myEnum = MyEnum.A
let myEnumIndex = myEnum.enumIndex(10)
println("myEnumIndex = \(myEnumIndex)")
```

will print:

myEnumIndex = 10